# How to add dropdown values to databse and also use it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to add the drop down value to the database and also calculate the total amount.
But if I add the value to the database then it is stored as numbers(since I need those values to calculate the total amount). Is there any way to resolve this issue?Thanks in advance.

```
                        <select id="package" required="" name="package">
                               <option data-value="19500">Himachal Pradesh Package 1</option>
                               <option data-value="20100">Himachal Pradesh Package 2</option>
                               <option data-value="11999">Rajasthan Package 1</option>
                               <option data-value="17999">Rajasthan Package 2</option>
                               <option data-value="10500">Kerala Package 1</option>
                               <option data-value="20000">KeralaPackage 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><br>
                     <label>Number of Passengers</label>
                            <input type="text" id="passengers" name="passengers" placeholder="" 
                              required="">
                            </div>
                            <button type="button"  id="ok" onclick="calcTip()"> OK</button><br/>

                   <script>
        
                  function calcTip(){

                 // grab the input values
                let tipAmount= document.getElementById("package").value;
                 let billAmount = document.getElementById("passengers").value;
               let billCard = document.getElementById("bill-card");

               //turn strings into numbers
               let tipAmountNumber = parseFloat(tipAmount);
             let billAmountNumber = parseFloat(billAmount);
    
            //grab elements
    
    let total = document.getElementById('total-p');

    // calculations
    let totalAmount = (tipAmount * billAmountNumber);
    let totalBill = totalAmount + billAmountNumber;

    //append content
    
      total.innerHTML = "Rs." + totalBill.toFixed(2);
    
    // show the bill info 
    billCard.style.display = "block";
    
}
```

when I add this package to the database it takes the amount values.

Comment: I can't understand what is the issue. How and where add you the values to database? I don't see any code about.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. They are two very different things. I corrected the tag for you.

Comment: P.s. I also don't understand the question / problem. Please edit your post to clarify what you mean